# How Collectors.groupingBy and Collectors.partitioningBy work in jdk8 internally?

Tags: java, java-8, grouping, partitioning

What is the internal structure and how does it work `groupingBy` and `partitioningBy` internally in `Java 8`.

FYI: I know what is use of `Collectors.groupingBy` and `Collectors.partitioningBy`.

Let's consider a stream of `Employee` objects:

```
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| Name     | City       | Number of Sales |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| Alice    | London     | 200             |
| Bob      | London     | 150             |
| Charles  | New York   | 160             |
| Dorothy  | Hong Kong  | 190             |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
```

**Grouping**: Consider we want to group `employee` who belong to same `city`.

```
Map<String, List<Employee>> employeesbycity =
  employees.stream().collect( Collectors.groupingBy(Employee::getCity));

Output: {New York=[Charles], Hong Kong=[Dorothy], London=[Alice, Bob]}
```

**Partitioning:** Partitioning is a special kind of grouping, in which the resultant map contains at most two different groups – one for true and one for false.

```
Map<Boolean, List<Employee>> partitioned = 
employees.stream().collect( Collectors.partitioningBy(e -> e.getNumSales() > 150));
```

**Output:**

```
{false=[Bob], true=[Alice, Charles, Dorothy]}
```

Comment: If you want to know how it works "internally", I suggest you open the source code. But if you want to understand what is the logic being both method, then you should [edit] the question. As for now, this can't be answered because the question is too broad

Comment: I assume you are talking about the collectors returned by [Collectors.groupingBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-) and [Collectors.partitioningBy](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#partitioningBy-java.util.function.Predicate-). Please clarify which aspects of the implementation of these collectors you are interested in. Also note that the OpenJdk exists, an OpenSource implementation where you can just look up the source code.

Comment: There is no magic. It’s basically the same as `Map<String, List<Employee>> employeesbycity = new HashMap<>(); for(Employee e: employees) employeesbycity.computeIfAbsent(e.getCity(), x -> new ArrayList<>()) .add(e);` The “internal structure” is the same `Map` you’ll get. Then, read about the [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/?java/util/stream/Collector.html) interface or about the [Mutable Reduction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html#MutableReduction) concept and think about how you can express the same logic as a `Collector`.

Comment: I accept that answer is not easy as it works but most important part is how it's work instead how to use it.